# Same method repeated multiple times

Tags: java

I started to use Android Studio, and I'm doing a basic project.
In this project there are 9 buttons that I control with the method setOnClickListener.
I have to repet this method 9 times, is there another way to control them?

**EDIT:**
This is what I've done so far:

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (b1.getText().toString().equals(""))
                if (turno == 1) {
                    turno = 2;
                    b1.setText("X");
                } else if (turno == 2) {
                    turno = 1;
                    b1.setText("O");
                }
            n_turni++;
            vincitore();
            b1.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (b2.getText().toString().equals(""))
                if (turno == 1) {
                    turno = 2;
                    b2.setText("X");
                } else if (turno == 2) {
                    turno = 1;
                    b2.setText("O");
                }
            n_turni++;
            vincitore();
            b2.setEnabled(false);
        }


    });

    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (b3.getText().toString().equals(""))
                if (turno == 1) {
                    turno = 2;
                    b3.setText("X");
                } else if (turno == 2) {
                    turno = 1;
                    b3.setText("O");
                }
            n_turni++;
            vincitore();
            b3.setEnabled(false);
        }


    });
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Android Studio. The IDE you are using to develop is irrelevant. You are asking about issues in the program, not about issues in the IDE.

Comment: I edited the post following your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: It seems to me the only difference is the button on which you operate in the OnClickListener. So one possibility to avoid code duplication is to create a method that returns a OnClickListener and takes a button as argument.

Comment: It's better to have multiple methods, rather than having conditions to check which button is clicked in one method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click method provides you already with a `View` parameter, which is the View (Button, in your case) that has been clicked.

So I'd suggest, you simply create your `OnClickListener` only once and assign it multiple times:
The key here is the cast of `v` to `Button`. So it works for all your buttons.

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button)v;
        if (b.getText().toString().equals(""))
            if (turno == 1) {
                turno = 2;
                b.setText("X");
            } else if (turno == 2) {
                turno = 1;
                b.setText("O");
            }
        n_turni++;
        vincitore();
        b.setEnabled(false);
    }
});

b1.setOnClickListener(listener);
b2.setOnClickListener(listener);    
b3.setOnClickListener(listener);
b4.setOnClickListener(listener);
b5.setOnClickListener(listener);    
b6.setOnClickListener(listener);
b7.setOnClickListener(listener);
b8.setOnClickListener(listener);    
b9.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter of type `View` to the method of the event handler. When called the this parameter will represent the view that was clicked. You can then either use its identity or content to determine which button it was and use the data.

See for the documentation of `View.OnClickListener` the Android documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Edit:
Now I've seen your code it is clearer to me what you mean.
Solutions:

1. Have your class implement View.OnClickListener and pass `this` as the parameter
2. Extract the method into another method and call this one from each anonymous handler, the pre-lambda variant of 3.
3. If your version of development supports lambdas pass a lamda function, which is a cleaner variant of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Create one common View.OnClickListener as

```
private View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
       if (v.getId() = button1.getId()){// do button1 click function}         
       if (v.getId() = button2.getId()){// do button2 click function}         
   }

};
button1.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
```

Assign buttonClickListener to all your buttons by setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener). To identify each button inside you onClick(View v) method compare v.getId() to your button.getId().

Same you can do by implementing View.OnClickListener to your class, which will ask you to override onClick method. So in your setOnClickListener simply pass `this` as your OnClickListener reference.

Answer (score 0):

In XML

```
    <Button

android:id="@+id/button1"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:text="TextButton"
/>

<Button

android:id="@+id/button2"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:text="TextButton2"
/>
```

In Java File

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

b.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

int id = v.getId();

switch(id) {

case R.id.button1: 

// execeute our code


break;
case R.id.button2: 

// execeute our code


break;


}
}
```

No matter how many buttons you put in layout, but it is required you have to register each button for click listener once

According to android architecture you can overrride a single function .ie  onClick() that will be called each time when click on button.You check which button was clicked by matching view ID.